# Devexpress extra tree list Focus node returns old value?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I wrote a C# program using DevExpress XtraTreelist.

When I focus the tree node by calling with its parent it returns the old value `0,0,0`

```
TreeListNode   trnNode = 
    (m_arrlstTypeData.Contains(trlstVariables.FocusedNode[colName].ToString()) ?
        trlstVariables.FocusedNode.ParentNode : trlstVariables.FocusedNode);
FocusColum = trnNode[colValues].ToString();
```

It sends `0,0,0`. What is the problem with this?

Comment: put your selection code of tree list..

Comment: I cant understand which selection sir >

Comment: `when i am focus the tree node by calling with its parent`.. how are you doing this??

Comment: Problem solved sir Actually i made a mistake of setting value as null in my code...because i have to perform Redo and Undo actions..now i got cleared... thanks for ur conversation :)

Comment: It's ok.. glad that you solved it yourself..